# Linking To Laravel's Public Directory from Javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am trying an open a project, but the project requires me to include a path of the library .js file. The library file is in Laravel's public directory. The file that requires the path is a javascript file, where I couldn't use `{{ asset() }}` to call as I normally do in html files in Laravel.

I mean, normally in html I use:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/ui-screenfull.js') }}"></script>
```

My question is, how do I link to a library that is in Laravel's public directory, inside javascript?

---

Both the library js files, and the requiring js file are in public folder, so as one way, I tried to give it normal path like:

(This is snippet from requiring javascript file):

```
uiLoad.load('../libs/screenfull/dist/screenfull.min.js');
```

but this doesn't work. Using this thinks it needs to get link content instead: `http://example.app/libs/screenfull/dist/screenfull.min.js` instead of `public/js/libs/screenfull/~`

I need to get the public directory or moving between paths.

---

The full file:

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    uiLoad.load('../libs/screenfull/dist/screenfull.min.js');
    $(document).on('click', '[ui-fullscreen]', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (screenfull.enabled) {
          screenfull.toggle();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Directory List:

```
public
  - scripts
       - requiring.js
  - libs
       - screenfull / dist / screenfull.min.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

One is - you can define this meta tag in inside your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="asset_url" content="{{ asset('/') }}"/>
```

Then assign the url to a variable:

```
var asset_url = $('meta[name=asset_url]').attr('content');
```

Then you can use the `asset_url` variable to refer the to public path:

```
uiLoad.load(asset_url + 'libs/screenfull/dist/screenfull.min.js');
```

Comment: The thing is it's inside a different javascript file, not in my html. How will I pass asset_url to the other javascript file?

Comment: Inside the javascript file you can put ```var asset_url = $('meta[name=asset_url]').attr('content');``` so that you can get the asset path